# Access and Display post values on a html page using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to display values in table cells in a form after they are posted by another form. Below is my code for that. Here I am trying to add the value of Select box in unbound_AdultVal hidden field using JQuery.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="summary.html" name="form">
<input id="unbound_CurrentStepID" type="hidden" value="Step_Two" name="unbound_CurrentStepID">
<input id="Unbound_AdultVal" type="hidden" value="" name="Unbound_AdultVal">

Ages 10+:

<select id="Unbound_Ticket" name="Unbound_Ticket">
<option selected="selected" value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Continue" name="submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">


  $(document).ready(function() {

var numDAdult = $("#Unbound_Ticket").val();

$("#Unbound_Ticket").change( function(){
    numDAdult = $("#Unbound_Ticket").val();

    $('input[name=Unbound_AdultVal]').val(numDAdult);
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Below is Summary.html code where I want to display the hidden field value.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="summary.html" name="form">
<input id="unbound_CurrentStepID" type="hidden" value="Form_Three" name="unbound_CurrentStepID">
<table width="800" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="381"><strong>Quantity</strong></td>
    <td width="242"><strong>Ticket Price</strong></td>
    <td width="139"><strong>Total Price</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span id="postAdultvalue"></span>
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" align="right"><strong>Current Amount Due: $0</strong></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">


  $(document).ready(function() {
$("#postAdultvalue").text($("#Unbound_AdultVal").val());
  });
  </script>
```

I am having a hard time displaying posted values in table using JQuery. As I am very new to JQuery please pardon my ignorance.

Comment: what exactly is wrong with your code? were is it failing for you?

Comment: It does not display anything. I am not able to get the select box value on my summary page. So I am trying to store select box value in a hidden field on index page, but when I try to display that value after form submit on summary page it does not display anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="Unbound_AdultVal" type="hidden" **value=""** name="Unbound_AdultVal">
```

The value needs to be set to the POST variable (ex. PHP: $_POST["name"], ColdFusion: #form.name#).

Comment: I am using JQuery to set the value dynamically. So  $('input[name=Unbound_AdultVal]').val(numDAdult); sets the Unbound hidden field value dynamically depending on selection in the Select bxo.

Comment: You should use a server side language, or do this all on one page.